# Density matrix derivation of an entangled state in amplitude dampling channel

Tags: density-matrix, decoherence

The density matrix for an entangled state when both the qubits decohere with probability D1 and D2 in amplitude damping channel is given as $\rho_d$ in  \href{https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2178}{this paper on page2}. I am reproducing it here,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
|\alpha^2|+|\beta^2|D_1 D_2 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{\bar{D_1}\bar{D_2}}\alpha^*\beta \\
0 & D_1 \bar{D_2}|\beta^2| & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & D_2 \bar{D_1}|\beta^2| & 0 \\
\sqrt{\bar{D_1}\bar{D_2}}\alpha\beta^* & 0 & 0 & \bar{D_2} \bar{D_1}|\beta^2|
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am deriving the same expression using amplitude damping modeling, but I am not getting these non-diagonal terms $\sqrt{\bar{D_1}\bar{D_2}}\alpha \beta $ at matrix element $a_{34}$ and $a_{43}$ positions.
Solving this using amplitude damping modeling we get,
$\alpha \vert 0_S\rangle \vert 0_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle$ = $\alpha \vert 0_S\rangle\vert 0_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle$
similarly,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\beta \vert 1_S\rangle\vert 1_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle & = \beta \bar{D_1}\bar{D_2}\vert 1_S\rangle \vert 1_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle\\ 
&=  \beta \bar{D_1}D_2\vert 1_S\rangle\vert 0_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle\\ &=\beta \bar{D_2}D_1\vert 0_S\rangle\vert 1_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle\\ &=\beta D_1 D_2\vert 0_S\rangle\vert 0_S\rangle \otimes \vert 0_E\rangle
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Considering the density matrix of the above terms we get all the diagonal terms of the matrix. But I am not getting these non-diagonal terms. Please explain.

Thank you.